# Displaying Score and Highscore in VBA 2048

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a 3x3 version of the 2048 game and am having trouble displaying the score and highscore. The score is supposed to be equal to the new cell value if two cells have merged.

Here is a sample of what I am working with (note 3x3 grid is "C4:E6"):

```
   ' Up button column C merging C5 into C4

   If Cells(5, 3).Value <> "" Then
        If Cells(5, 3).Value = Cells(4, 3).Value Then
            Cells(4, 3).Value = Cells(4, 3).Value * 2
            Cells(5, 3).Value = Cells(6, 3).Value
            Cells(6, 3).Value = ""
            Points = Points + Cells(4, 3).Value
                Cells(4, 6).Value = Points
            nudgeCell = True
        End If
    End If
```

The "Points" row is really what I'm concerned with and the points should be displayed in Cell F4 (Cells(4, 6))

The highscore code is as follows:

```
' Highscore
If Cells(4, 6).Value > Cells(5, 6).Value Then
    Cells(4, 6).Value = Cells(5, 6).Value
Else
    Cells(4, 6).Value = Cells(4, 6).Value
End If
```

Where the highscore is put into Cell F5 (Cell(5, 6)).
The problem is that the scores are not showing up in the actual cells on the worksheet. What did I do wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that this line

```
If Cells(4, 6).Value > Cells(5, 6).Value Then
```

should be changed to

```
If Cells(4, 6).Value < Cells(5, 6).Value Then
```

This is only based on the limited code you've shown, which only reveals that the points value (1) is located in cells(4,6), (2) it is the sum of whatever has occupied cells(4,3), and (3) if the cells(5,6) value is greater, it will be replaced by that smaller value. Since you say "the scores are not showing up" I wonder if the cells(5,6) value is ever blank (ie, zero) -- since if that ever happens, the points value will always be blank thereafter (assuming all scores are >0).

Comment: Thanks Tony! I actually didn't spot the problem with the < and >, you have a sharp eye! The score in Cells(4,6) now appears, but the highscore still isn't appearing (supposed to be in Cells(5,6)). Have I missed something there?

Comment: I'd like to help further, but I don't see where the code you've provided changes cells(5,6) so I can't. In any event, I'm glad you've been helped to some degree. Please mark as answered once you're satisfied you've been helped.

Comment: Hmmm... the Highscore code is actually the entire bit of code already, seems like I may be missing some code here. I'll keep working on it, thanks!